# function for squaring numbers not printing output for numbers < 1

Tags: python

Hi I am trying to make  a function where it squares all numbers from 1 to `number`(which is given to function at the end of the code). I also made it so I had an if statement so it checks if numbers is < 1 it prints "error", but when I put 0 as the input, it just does nothing?

```
def print_squares_to_number(number):
    """takes number and prints a table of all integers and their squares from one to number"""
    for numbers in range(1, number + 1):
        if numbers < 1:
            print("ERROR: number must be at least 1")
        else:
            print(numbers, "*", numbers, "=", numbers*numbers)

print_squares_to_number(0)
print_squares_to_number(5)
print_squares_to_number(3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop part is iterating from `1` to the `input_integer+1`. Thus if you give 0 or any negative integer, `range(1, number+1)` turns into a vacant iterable, thus it doesn't print anything.

Try this :

```
def print_squares_to_number(number):
    """takes number and prints a table of all integers and their squares from one to number"""
    if number < 1:
        print("ERROR: number must be at least 1")
    else:
        for numbers in range(1, number + 1):
            print(numbers, "*", numbers, "=", numbers*numbers)

print_squares_to_number(0)
print_squares_to_number(5)
print_squares_to_number(-1)
```

**OUTPUT** :

```
ERROR: number must be at least 1
1 * 1 = 1
2 * 2 = 4
3 * 3 = 9
4 * 4 = 16
5 * 5 = 25
ERROR: number must be at least 1
```

Comment: oh so should I just use `range(number + 1)`

Comment: Check `if number < 1: ...` first thing before the `for` loop.